# android -How to route onitemselected in the spinner listener to method onstate selected ?..Its not going to second if else

Tags: android, spinner

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_fragment, container, false);

        bankListSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        stateListSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        districtListSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        branchListSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner4);

        bankListSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        final Button resultBtn=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

        resultBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {

                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                IFSCResultScene llf = new IFSCResultScene();
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment1, llf);
                ft.addToBackStack("tag");
                ft.commit();

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });



        return  view;
    }


    @Override
    public void showBankList(ArrayList<Bank> bankNames) {

        this.banks = bankNames;
        ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, bankNames);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        bankListSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


    }

    @Override
    public void showBankStateList(ArrayList<State> stateNames) {
        this.states = stateNames;
        ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stateNames);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        stateListSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void showDistrict(ArrayList<District> districtNames) {
        this.districts = districtNames;
        ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, districtNames);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        districtListSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


    }

    @Override
    public void showBranches(ArrayList<Bank> bankNames) {
        this.banks = bankNames;
  ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = newArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, bankNames);     dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        branchListSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    }
*/


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {



        if(adapterView.getId()==R.id.spinner1) {

            ifscSceneHandler.onBankSelected(banks.get(i));



        }else  if(adapterView.getId()==R.id.spinner2) {
            ifscSceneHandler.onStateSelected(states.get(i));

        }
        else  if(adapterView.getId()==R.id.spinner3) {
            //ifscSceneHandler.onStateSelected(states.get(i));

        }
        else  if(adapterView.getId()==R.id.spinner4) {
            //ifscSceneHandler.onStateSelected(states.get(i));

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
}
```

Comment: something wrong with your IDs

Comment: when i click on spinner 2 's data ..its showing .. Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.

Comment: show how you findById your spinners, how you set your listeners, and your XML. The general way to solve your problem is to use different listeners for each spinner.

Comment: how can we use onitemselected for diffrent spinner

Comment: same way as you do it for single spinner

Comment: how i can diffrenitate onitemselected fro diffrent spinner ?

Comment: call `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener` on a different spinner, it's obvious. show how you set `onItemSelectedListener` in your project.

Comment: bankListSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); this way

Comment: you pass `this` as a parameter. pass another listener to each spinner instead

Comment: i have provided whole code up

Comment: am calling stateListSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); but now there are two setonitemselectedlisteners ..how to resolve it

Comment: ok, firstly you set listener only to `bankListSpinner`, not to other 3 spinners. Why?

Comment: am doing one by one ...my first listener is working fyn...now i want my second to work

Comment: hey my problem is resolved thanx :)

Comment: have you tried adding `stateListSpinner .setOnItemSelectedListener(this);`?

Comment: how is it resolved?

Comment: yaaa i tried stateListSpinner .setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

Comment: thats how it resolved

Answer (score 0):

you don't add `setOnItemSelectedListener` to 3 other spinners. You should add it to them:

```
 bankListSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
 stateListSpinner .setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
 districtListSpinner .setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
 branchListSpinner .setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```